# Boost.Log: add_console_log ambiguous when used with Phoenix stream format?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, c++11

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here. I'm setting up logging like so in my C++11 app:

```
    auto format = expr::stream
        << "[" << expr::attr<Severity>("Severity") << "] "
        << expr::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") << ": "
        << expr::message;

    add_console_log(std::clog, keywords::format = format);
    add_file_log("isis.log", keywords::format = format);

    add_common_attributes();
```

This works great with the add_file_log call, as expected. But the add_console_log call I am getting a compile error about it being ambiguous. I'll admit my own weakness here in finding some of these deep template based errors to be nearly indecipherable, but it seems to me that this ought to be a relatively standard use case.

I really don't want to paste the entire error string (it's huge), but here's the important part:

```
error C2668: 'boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::add_console_log' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>          c:\code\boost_1_55_0\boost\log\utility\setup\console.hpp(134): could be 'boost::shared_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::synchronous_sink<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_ostream_backend>> boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::add_console_log<char,boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<Keyword,boost::phoenix::actor<Expr>>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,const ArgT1 &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Keyword=boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::keywords::tag::format
1>  ,            Expr=boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::expressions::aux::attribute_output_terminal<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::expressions::aux::attribute_output_terminal<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<2>>,0>>,boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<char [2]>,0>>>,2>>,Isis::Severity,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::fallback_to_none,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::to_log_fun<void>>>,boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<char [3]>,0>>>,2>>,boost::posix_time::ptime,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::fallback_to_none,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::light_function<void (boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::basic_formatting_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &,const boost::posix_time::ptime &)>>>,boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<char [3]>,0>>>,2>>,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::expressions::attribute_actor<boost::mpl::vector2<std::string,std::wstring>,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::fallback_to_none,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::expressions::tag::message,boost::phoenix::actor>>,2>
1>  ,            ArgT1=boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::keywords::tag::format,boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::expressions::aux::attribute_output_terminal<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::expressions::aux::attribute_output_terminal<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<2>>,0>>,boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<char [2]>,0>>>,2>>,Isis::Severity,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::fallback_to_none,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::to_log_fun<void>>>,boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<char [3]>,0>>>,2>>,boost::posix_time::ptime,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::fallback_to_none,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::light_function<void (boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::basic_formatting_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &,const boost::posix_time::ptime &)>>>,boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<char [3]>,0>>>,2>>,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::expressions::attribute_actor<boost::mpl::vector2<std::string,std::wstring>,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::fallback_to_none,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::expressions::tag::message,boost::phoenix::actor>>,2>>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\code\boost_1_55_0\boost\log\utility\setup\console.hpp(60): or       'boost::shared_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::synchronous_sink<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_ostream_backend>> boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::add_console_log<char,boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<Keyword,boost::phoenix::actor<Expr>>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,const ArgsT &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Keyword=boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::keywords::tag::format
1>  ,            Expr=boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::expressions::aux::attribute_output_terminal<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::expressions::aux::attribute_output_terminal<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<2>>,0>>,boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<char [2]>,0>>>,2>>,Isis::Severity,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::fallback_to_none,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::to_log_fun<void>>>,boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<char [3]>,0>>>,2>>,boost::posix_time::ptime,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::fallback_to_none,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::light_function<void (boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::basic_formatting_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &,const boost::posix_time::ptime &)>>>,boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<char [3]>,0>>>,2>>,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::expressions::attribute_actor<boost::mpl::vector2<std::string,std::wstring>,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::fallback_to_none,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::expressions::tag::message,boost::phoenix::actor>>,2>
1>  ,            ArgsT=boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::keywords::tag::format,boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::expressions::aux::attribute_output_terminal<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::expressions::aux::attribute_output_terminal<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<2>>,0>>,boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<char [2]>,0>>>,2>>,Isis::Severity,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::fallback_to_none,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::to_log_fun<void>>>,boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<char [3]>,0>>>,2>>,boost::posix_time::ptime,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::fallback_to_none,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::light_function<void (boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::basic_formatting_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &,const boost::posix_time::ptime &)>>>,boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<char [3]>,0>>>,2>>,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::expressions::attribute_actor<boost::mpl::vector2<std::string,std::wstring>,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::fallback_to_none,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::expressions::tag::message,boost::phoenix::actor>>,2>>>
1>          ]
```

As an added piece of info, it doesn't matter if I use the format as a variable as I am in the code, or if I move the entire format block to be inline to the add_console_log call. The documentation clearly states that both add_file_log and add_console_log should accept stream style formatting blocks, so I'm at a loss. I don't even know where to begin in terms of casting the format argument to get rid of the ambiguity (if that's even the answer).

Compiler is Visual C++ 12 (Visual Studio 2013).

Comment: I can't test it, but I think that using `boost::log::add_console_log` (or `logging::add_console_log` if you use `namespace logging=boost::log`, as it's done in the examples) could work.

Comment: That did it, and really parsing the error showed me why. There is a different version of add_console_log in an aux namespace, and it was getting brought in with the primary versions. Good catch. If you turn it in to an answer, I'll make it as correct.

I think the real issue was that I was doing "using namespace boost::log" which is bringing them both in to the global namespace.

Comment: The most I can offer is "could work" and that is not enough for an answer. I'm sure there are many people that will be able to give a better answer.